# Application to integrate gmail in unity

Tags: unity, gmail

I want to write an application that will integrate Gmail into unity please help me.
PS I dont want to use previous applications like Gmail notifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation and API examples can be found here.

http://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/unity/

A few tutorial can be found here to help you with starting [Not so much for now]

http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/all/

if you are concerned with gmail unread count, there is already an solution for this.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/08/unity-mail-gmail-count-desktop-launcher-ubuntu/